# ng-switch-when value from an ng-repeat not displaying value

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I have this simple code. The problem is that `"ng-switch-when"` is not displaying, which means that `column.stage` is not being rendered correctly, although I tried displaying `{{column.stage}}` and it displays the correct value (1 OR 2 OR 3...)

```
<div class="column span3" ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <h1>{{column.title}}</h1>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="shot in shots" ng-switch on="shot.stage">
        <h6 ng-switch-when="{{column.stage}}">{{shot.title}}</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ng-switch on="shot.stage" in its own element like:

```
<div class="column span3" ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <h1>{{column.title}}</h1>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="shot in shots">
        <div ng-switch on="shot.stage">
          <h6 ng-switch-when="{{column.stage}}">{{shot.title}}</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think we can put variable at `ng-switch-when`. Unfortunatly.